# Prestashop 1.5 How to skip payment step in checkout?

Tags: prestashop-1.5

I am using PS 1.5.6.0. I am using only one payment method, because of that i want to skip payment step and redirect customer from carrier step to my payment module page.

Answer (score 0):

By Default it is not possible in 5 steps checkout process, but if you use the One Page Checkout, then it may work for you (not exactly like your question).

In One Page checkout, all steps for order are displayed at cart page, where user can login / register , add / edit addresses, select shipping options and at bottom the payment options. So user will enter all the details, scroll down to page and then just click on the payment module logo, and the user will be sent to payment page.

I hope you will like it this way.

Comment: Hello, thanx, i knew that, but i need it in 5 steps checkout.

Comment: Then it will require some core changes in the system.

Comment: I know, because of that i asked for help in this place. I know how to do this in ps 1.4, but it doesn't work in ps 1.5

Comment: How to Enable One Page Check out from Admin side ?

Comment: Got admin and then Preferences menu. In preferences menu click on Orders. On the page you will see " Order process type " . Select One Page Checkout from the drop down list. Thank you